# i18n with ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource in Spring - <spring:message> tag not parsed

Tags: spring, tags, resources, xhtml, message

i set up ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource as shown in spring documentation. I am using the following page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

...
<b><spring:message code="general.welcome"/></b> ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}
...
```

When running the application and inspecting the source code i still see:

```
<b><spring:message code="general.welcome"/>
```

without rendering the message defined in the messages_en.properties file.

How can i get more information to track what is happening and the tag is not rendered as mentioned message output?

Thanks & kindest regards,
ArnKor

Comment: It isn't a JSF tag but JSP tag. I doubt it will work in a JSF environment.

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, thanks for commenting on that. Ok, this maybe the reason it is not working. What would be a recommended way to implement i18n then? My application specification: JSF with Primefaces, Spring, JPA via Hibernate.